# How realistic is the MMA TV series "Kingdom"?

Tags: mma

The MMA TV series "Kingdom" seems to equate MMA trainees to very troubled & bravado-driven characters from broken pasts.  Is this typical of MMA clubs in reality?  Or are they in reality more humble and down to earth?  Hollywood tends to amplify "characters" to create tension and conflict, and I'm wondering how much this makes up the portrayal.

Comment: It is no different to the Hollywood stereotype of boxing clubs.

Comment: Is that to say that trainees are actually more normal and there is usually a lot less drama-generating circumstances surrounding individuals, their pasts, and their relationships?

Comment: It's simply to say that this sort of stereotyping isn't new and can be applied to depictions of any similar sport.  Or, for that matter, any sport at all.

Comment: It sounds to me like most MMA gyms aren't fraught with so much drama.  I mean, all the alcohol, smoking, drugs, and gang threats, drug addicted sex-working parents, no stable household in which one can get proper rest, etc. It's extreme for hollywood depictions of sports, so I was wondering whether it specific to MMA.